# Is there a way to share In-memory db between processes?

Tags: sqlite

My c++ client on linux uses sqlite3, and I am planning to open the same db with node.js.
That is, I mean I want to use the same database file between other processes, not threads.

On my windows, I ran sqlite3.exe on two cmd shells.

In 1st cmd shell,

> sqlite3.exe
>   sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared' AS aux1;
>   sqlite> create table items ( name varchar(20) );
>   sqlite> insert into items (name) values ('item1');

In 2nd cmd shell,

> sqlite3.exe
>   sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared' AS aux1;
>   sqlite> select * from items;
>   Error: no such table: items

Any suggestion or comment would be thankful.

Comment: As a sidenote, I tested with sqlite 3.8.7.1 on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) says that

> all database connections sharing the in-memory database need to be in the same process.

You need to use a file, or write your own shared-memory [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) and recompile both your program and node.js to use it.

Comment: Thank so much for your suggestion on VFS.